# wiping device and re-entering account info reloads all previously loaded apps

Tags: factory-reset, google-account, restore, reformat

My phone was running quite slow so I decided to wipe it and re-enter my account info into it. After I did that all the apps I had previously had installed started re-downloading themselves. My contact list was restored as well.

idk if I mind the contact list (altho I had written down all the names / numbers I wanted to keep) but the apps re-installing themselves is a bit of a PITA. I could start uninstalling every app under the sun but as a matter of personal preference the apps that came with the phone (even if they're not a part of Android itself) I'd just assume keep. And plus it just seems like it'd be easier to start from scratch and selectively install the apps I know I want instead of uninstall the apps I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your device and android version. When setting up the device on Lollipop 5.0+, When you get to the part about "Get your apps and data" From the drop down select "Set up as new device." If on KitKat 4.X.X, When you get to Google Services setup screen, uncheck the "Backup and Restore" option. Once the device is setup and whatnot. If you go back into the settings, you should be able to recheck it without it trying to download all the apps again, but only after the initial setup is complete.

**Edit**

[Photo of Kitkat screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYU2C.jpg)

[Photo of Lollipop screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBZWn.jpg)